# What to use instead of subscribe() for an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I'd like to close a login dialog whenever the Firebase authState changes. I read online that I the `subscribe()` function would cause data leaks if the `unsubscribe()` function isn't called and therefore, want to replace the function. Here is my code:

```
this.user = this.auth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap( (user) => {
    if(user) {
      return (this.firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).valueChanges() as Observable<User>)
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);
```

I'd like to replace the `subscribe` function here with something else:

```
this.authService.user.subscribe( (user) => {
  if(user) {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
})
```

This is what I tried, but I think I'm using the map function incorrectly:

```
this.authService.user.pipe(
  map( (user) => {
    if(user) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  })
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would the `Observable.toPromise()` fit the bill?

Comment: You can use operators such as `take(1)` or `takeUntil()` to make sure it the chain always completes. `toPromise()` will not make leaks only if the Observable completes so I think there's not reason to avoid using `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subscribe` function in itself is not bad, or any memory leak. It becomes an issue when you do not unsubscribe the `Subscription` or complete the `Observable` when the component code or service code is destroyed.

But it all depends on what you want to do:

If this is a global listener in a root service. You do not have to care about it, because the life cycle of the service is the same as your entire app.

If it's a listener in a component, you need to make sure to unsubscribe from it when the component is destroyed:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  checkLogin(): void {
    this.authService.user.pipe(
      filter((user) => !!user),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((user) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.dialogRef.close();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

Judging by your code it feels like you are using angular material as well, and you are actually waiting for a user to login. Then this would be the most appropriate solution:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  checkLogin(): void {
    this.authService.user.pipe(
      filter((user) => !!user),
      take(1),
      takeUntil(this.dialogRef.beforeClosed)
    ).subscribe((user) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.dialogRef.close();
    });
  }
}
```

This unsubscribes when:

- the dialog is closed by using `takeUntil(...)`
- after the first emit of the `AuthService` with a user by using `filter(...)` and `take(1)`

And only in the second case will it reach the subscribed method

Comment: Thank you so much! ```takeUntil()``` was what I was missing. I needed to edit your code for it to work as I wanted it to. Here's what I am using: 
```this.authService.user.pipe(
      map(user => !!user),
      takeUntil(this.dialogRef.beforeClosed())
    ).subscribe( (isLoggedIn) => {
      if(isLoggedIn) {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    });```